# Running Jenkins Azure Slave jobs as a specific Windows user (not 'Local System')

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, azure-powershell, jenkins-agent

We have an MSBuild we're running on Jenkins using the [Azure Slave Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-slave-plugin/blob/master/README.md).

**The jobs seem to run on the slave as user `nt authority\system`. How can we change this to a user of our choice?**

---

So far, we are using default init script for the slave VMs (the VM template has everything preinstalled - JDK, Visual Studio, etc)

The job runs as `Ant => Powershell [=> MSBuild, Azure commands]]`

The last step (deployment commands) is the problem. We are logging into Azure with a certificate. Powershell:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString <...> -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("...", $secpasswd)
Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $mytenant -Credential $mycreds
```

This succeeds! but says the user has no subscriptions.

*The build works fine when run by the correct user, through an RDP session*.

The Jenkins job is trying to run as `nt authority\system`. I think it is failing to reach the Windows certificate store.